# Open a file/folder from a specified cell

Tags: vba, excel

I would appreciate any help with this! I'm trying to figure out the correct code in order to pull from folder *"2017"* (shown below) dynamically. Within this folder there are many excel workbooks. From there the vba copies and pastes a range of cells into the original workbook. So far the code is very manual, where whenever I try to switch the folder origin I have to manually change it within the code.

Would someone be able to assist me on editing the code to be dynamic? For example: what I'm hoping to achieve is that if the folder's name is in cell *A1*. Then the vba code would open the folder and pull the workbooks from whatever name was in cell *A1*.

Please let me know if there's any additional information I could provide!

Thank you in Advance!

```
  Sub ArrDepMerge2017()


Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Dim c As Long

Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("2017")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files

For Each everyObj In filesObj
    Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
    c = c + 1
    bookList.Sheets(1).Range("F37:F53").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2017 Data").Cells(1, c)
    bookList.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder(Range("A1").value2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign a cell value to a variable e.g. path and then use that within your GetFolder. Also, add the Next everyobj when using For Each.

```
Sub ArrDepMerge2017()

Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Dim c As Long
Dim path as String

path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mysheetname").Range("myrange")

Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder(path)
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files

For Each everyObj In filesObj
    Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
    c = c + 1
    bookList.Sheets(1).Range("F37:F53").Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2017 Data").Cells(1, c)
    bookList.Close
Next everyObj ' this was missing

End Sub
```